# How do I create dynamic methods with string interpolation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the code below but it fails to run:

```
%w(acp bcp ccp tcp).each do |kind|
    define_method(kind+"_name") { send "[#{kind}_title ? #{kind}_title.title : '',#{kind}_firstname,#{kind}_lastname].join(' ')" }
 end
```

And when running it:

```
> Form.last.acp_name
NoMethodError: undefined method `[acp_title ? acp_title.title : '',acp_firstname,acp_lastname].join(' ')' for #<Form:0x108daabe8>
```

Anybody has any idea how to fix it so as to run as code and not as literal please?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Refactoring means to simplify the code without changing its behaviour. Fixing a bug is not refactoring because code that doesn't run and code that does behave differently.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed correctly said and question improved!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%w(acp bcp ccp tcp).each do |kind|
  define_method("#{ kind }_name") do
    title = send("#{ kind }_title") || ''
    array = [ title, send("#{ kind }_firstname"), send("#{ kind }_lastname")]
    array.join(' ')
  end
end
```